# write_csv Scientific notation depending on trailing "000"?

Tags: r, csv, format, tidyverse, readr

Writing a csv with the write_csv() function from package readr seems to treat numbers differently depending on trailing zeros.

- 4001705344 is saved as is, but
- 4100738000 is saved as 4100738e3 in the csv.

This causes problems when I reopen the csv (e.g. in Excel).

For a reproducible example s.

```
    library(readr)
    x <- c(4100750938, 4104806156, 4001682199, 4100738000)
    df <- data.frame(x) 
    write_csv(df, "df.csv")
```

The result is

```
    x
    4100750938
    4104806156
    4001682199
    4100738e3
```

The expected result is

```
    x
    4100750938
    4104806156
    4001682199
    4100738000
```

The only thing that helps is to save x as a character vector, which keeps the 000 intact and produces the expected output.

```
    library(readr)
    x <- c(4100750938, 4104806156, 4001682199, 4100738000)
    x <- as.character(x)
    df <- data.frame(x) 
    write_csv(df, "df.csv")
```

But is there another way? And is write_csv() behaving correctly here?

I use readr_1.1.1 on 
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

Browsing other Questions I found [write_csv read_csv with scientific notation after 1000th row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48218646/write-csv-read-csv-with-scientific-notation-after-1000th-row) but that seems do be a different question to me.

Comment: Please see : https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/issues/671 If you use integers than you can follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30341140/readr-turn-off-scientific-notation-in-write-csv

Comment: options(digits=18)
write.csv(df, "myfile.csv")

Comment: Thanks - this works! I try to stay with the readr package - it seems that the devs think about integrating an option or drop the automatic formatting, s. https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/pull/679

Comment: Great! I added this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
write_csv(df, "df.csv",fileEncoding = "UTF-16LE")
```

Comment: This returns 
        Error in write_csv(df, "df.csv", fileEncoding = "UTF-16LE"): unused argument (fileEncoding = "UTF-16LE")

Did you mean
write.csv(df, "df.csv", fileEncoding = "UTF-16LE")?
But this would not return the expected output either.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use regular write.csv() function and set options():

```
x <- c(4100750938, 4104806156, 4001682199, 4100738000)
df <- data.frame(x) 

options(digits=15) 
write.csv(df, "myfile.csv", row.names = FALSE)

system("cat myfile.csv")
# "x"
# 4100750938
# 4104806156
# 4001682199
# 4100738000
```